# How to get data from custom created function in JS using https node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get data from my function `Data()` instead of JSON PLACE HOLDER mock API using HTTPS/HTTP node module and how to make an endpoint of this get data HTTP/HTTPS module to utilize response in front end just like Angular?

My mock backen.js file:

```
const https = require('https');
 
https.get(Data.data, res => {
  let data = [];
  const headerDate = res.headers && res.headers.date ? res.headers.date : 'no response date';
  console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('Date in Response header:', headerDate);

  res.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Response ended: ');
    const users = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(data).toString());

    for(user of users) {
      console.log(`Got user with id: ${user.id}, name: ${user.name}`);
    }
  });
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message);
});



function Data() {
  var data = {};
 ........
   return data;
 }
```

Your time and help will be really appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurray! I got it using the following code and Express in node js. I simply call my custom method that creates data into an express "get" endpoint. When I hit the end point the response will be my custom method result.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
res.send(
  getDashboardData());
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
});



function Data() {
  var data = {};
  ..........
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   return JSON.stringify(data);
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).